# Generate Dynamic LINQ Expression By Iterating object properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

I am trying to loop through all properties in an object including nested objects and objects in collections to generate LINQ expressions. The structure of my classes as follows:

```
public class Rule
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
}
public class QueryBuilder
{

    public string condition { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }

}
```

bellow is the example JSON for the above entity mapping

```
{
"condition": "and",
"rules": [
    {
        "condition": "or",
        "rules": [
            {
                "label": "PaymentMode",
                "field": "PaymentMode",
                "operator": "equal",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "Cash"
            },
            {
                "label": "TransactionType",
                "field": "TransactionType",
                "operator": "equal",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "expensive"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "condition": "or",
        "rules": [
            {
                "label": "Date",
                "field": "Date",
                "operator": "equal",
                "type": "date",
                "value": "4/15/21"
            },
            {
                "label": "Date",
                "field": "Date",
                "operator": "equal",
                "type": "date",
                "value": "4/15/21"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The above json will be in a hierarchy. User can select any number of AND or OR condition. Need to make bellow expression inside a recursive loop

```
var constant = Expression.Constant("Jhon");
              var property = Expression.Property(paramExpr,"FirstName");
              expression = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

              constant = Expression.Constant("Ram");
              property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "LastName");
              var expression2 = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
              expression = Expression.Or(expression, expression2);
```

How can I make a recursive loop with the above structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
    public Expression BuildExpression(ParameterExpression paramExpr, Rule rule)
    {
        if (rule.condition != null)
        {
            if (rule.condition != "or" && rule.condition != "and")
                throw new Exception($"Condition [{rule.condition}] is invalid.");

            if (rule.rules == null || rule.rules.Count < 2)
                throw new Exception($"Cannot create [{rule.condition}] expression.");

            IList<Expression> expressions = rule.rules
                .Select(rule => BuildExpression(paramExpr, rule))
                .ToList();

            if (rule.condition == "or")
                return JoinExpressions(expressions, (left, right) => Expression.OrElse(left, right));
            else
                return JoinExpressions(expressions, (left, right) => Expression.AndAlso(left, right));
        }
        else
        {
            Expression constant = Expression.Constant(rule.value);
            Expression property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, rule.field);

            // added to allow any value to be included.
            if (rule.value == "ANY")
            {
                Type type = GetType(rule.type);
                if (!type.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    constant = Expression.Constant(null, type);

                    switch (rule.@operator)
                    {
                        case "equal": return Expression.NotEqual(property, constant);
                        case "notequal": return Expression.Equal(property, constant);
                        default:
                            throw new Exception($"Operator [{rule.@operator}] is invalid for ANY filter. Use only equal or notequal.");
                    }
                }

                constant = property;
            }

            switch (rule.@operator)
            {
                case "equal": return Expression.Equal(property, constant);
                case "notequal": return Expression.NotEqual(property, constant);
                case "greaterthan": return Expression.GreaterThan(property, constant);
                case "greaterthanorequal": return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, constant);
                case "lessthan": return Expression.LessThan(property, constant);
                case "lessthanorequal": return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constant);
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Operator [{rule.@operator}] is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }

    public Expression JoinExpressions(IList<Expression> expressions, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> join)
    {
        Expression andExpression = null;

        foreach (Expression expression in expressions)
        {
            if (andExpression == null)
                andExpression = expression;
            else
                andExpression = join(andExpression, expression);
        }

        return andExpression;
    }

    public static Type GetType(string typeName)
    {
        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "string": return typeof(string);
            ... add any others.
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Type [{typeName}] is invalid.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will implement this and update here in few minutes

Comment: Note, just changed it slightly on checking the value of 'condition'

Comment: Another note, you will need to define the var 'constant' using the given type and ensure your constant value is parsed to the correct type based on whatever format you're expecting in the string.

Comment: I think this condition(rule.rules.Count != 2) will make issue,Can u please tell me what is the use of this. In case if its only 1 condition then this will throw issue

Comment: It's only there where the condition is "or" or "and". Both of these require 2 arguments.

Comment: in some case my rule.rules[] have more than 2 condition, on that time it is not taking the 3rd condition because of this
 Expression left = BuildExpression(paramExpr, rule.rules[0]);
 Expression right = BuildExpression(paramExpr, rule.rules[1]);
how can I make this work for multiple conditions

Comment: I have updated the answer. This needs a separate method to join the expressions which will include as many as are specified. I also realised that Expression.And and Expression.Or were not the correct methods to be using as these are for bitwise logical operations so I changed these to Expression.AndAlso and Expression.OrElse.

Comment: Need to implement ANY in propertyValue. Like FIrstName=ANY can u help me please

Comment: I've added a small change to do this. The result of a value of 'ANY' would now be that the filter is added as `property = property`. Not sure if this is exactly what you need. It could instead prevent the filter from being added at all but you'd have to manage the possibility of ending up with no expression on one side of the OR or AND so the code would get more complicated. Also that might prevent certain functionality that you might intend with having this filter. I am also not sure if you meant ANY to be a not null indicator instead which would be different.

Comment: ya I want not null indicator only. For example if some 1 select firstName = ANY then all rows should fetch

Comment: that constant we are adding with NULL/ DBNull.value will throw an run time exception if our property field (like empId) NOT NULL. bellow is the exception 
The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.DBNull'.

Comment: above edit is still working for nullable type for non nullable its not working

Comment: Added a check if the type is a primitive type. If it is then it does not check for null.