# Create LINQ expression Tree with multiple OR and AND condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression

I want to generate LINQ expression tree with nested AND or OR condition. I have bellow expressions

```
    var constant = Expression.Constant("Jhon");
    var property = Expression.Property(paramExpr,"FirstName");
    var expression = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
    constant = Expression.Constant("12");
    property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "Age");
    var expression2 = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

    expressionMain1 = Expression.AND(expression, expression2);

    constant = Expression.Constant("Mathew");
    property = Expression.Property(paramExpr,"LastName");
    expression = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
    constant = Expression.Constant("19");
    property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "Age");
    expression2 = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

    expressionMain2 = Expression.And(expression, expression2);
```

I want the final lambda query like

```
(FirstName='John' AND Age='12') OR (LastName='Mathew' AND Age= '19')
```

Comment: Linq does not work with nesting.  Besides expression trees must be done with recursion to properly work under ANY condition.

Comment: @jdweng : can u please give an expression for above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
Expression.OrElse(expressionMain1, expressionMain2)
```

Comment: this will not add Brackets in between 2 main AND queries and the result will be different

Comment: What would you need brackets for? The ANDs will be evaluated and then the ORs. Brackets would make no difference. I assure you if it was the other way around then 'brackets' would be expected but this is an expression tree so even then it would still work.

Comment: I think this both query 
(FirstName='John' AND Age='12') OR (LastName='Mathew' AND Age= '19')  
FirstName='John' AND Age='12' OR LastName='Mathew' AND Age= '19'
Will give different answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the same thing and will not give a different answer!

Comment: so if the query is in other way like (FirstName='John' OR Age='12') AND (LastName='Mathew' OR Age= '19') then how can I achieve  that.

Comment: Yes the brackets matter in this case, however being an expression tree rather than typed code, the hierarchy will be automatically assumed. So you would create your two OR expressions and wrap them in an AND expression. The result will be correct.

Comment: so for this scenario (FirstName='John' OR Age='12') AND (LastName='Mathew' OR Age= '19') if I use Expression.AND(expressionMain1, expressionMain2) will work ?

Comment: can you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104241/generate-dynamic-linq-expression-by-iterating-object-properties and if you have any suggestion please provide

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

Comment: @SteveHarris, it is beginners bug. It should be `Expression.OrElse`.

Comment: Yes, AndAlso and OrElse